# typescript: how to narrow object with union type PROPERTY

Tags: typescript

recently i encounter a case where i need to narrow a obj with union type property.
Below are simplified version of what i'm trying to achieve.

```js
interface typeA{
  id: number,
  status: 0 | 1,
}
interface typeB extends typeA {
  status: 1,
}

function log(param: typeB){
  // only accepts status = 1
}
```

but when trying to use `function log` with data that is typeA, I'll encounter following error:

```
Argument of type 'typeA' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeB'.
  Types of property 'status' are incompatible.
    Type '0 | 1' is not assignable to type '1'.
      Type '0' is not assignable to type '1'
```

code:

```js
const data1: typeA = {id: 1, status: 0}

data1.status = 1

if(data1.status === 1){
  data1.status // when hovered, typescript can correctly identify that data1.status is 1
  log(data1) // error here
}
```

i currently overcome the error like so but im not sure if there is a better typescript operator so solve my issue

```js
if(data1.status === 1){
  log({...data1, status: data1.status})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Together with 1) constructing an ad-hoc object as you have shown, which is an acceptable solution anyway but is often unnecessary extra-coding, there are essentially two other ways here: 2) the "proper" way which is with a type predicate [*]; and 3) the fact that in TS you can always force the type of a term via casting, in the worst case by casting to `any`, which amounts to disabling type checking altogether, for that term as well as for any expression containing that term.

Here is an example of 3) and 2) respectively, starting from the code you have shown:

```
interface typeA {
  id: number,
  status: 0 | 1,
}

interface typeB extends typeA {
  status: 1,
}

function log(param: typeB) {
  param.status;  // (property) typeB.status: 1
}

const data1: typeA = { id: 1, status: 0 };

if (data1.status === 1) {
  // here TS still considers `data1` of `typeA`
  // and has no reason to do otherwise, so we
  // force-cast, at our own risk and peril (!):
  log(data1 as typeB);  // cast
}

// this is a type predicate (see the return type):
function isTypeB(obj: typeA): obj is typeB {
  return obj.status === 1;
}

if (isTypeB(data1)) {
  // now TS *knows* `data1` is of `typeB`:
  log(data1);
}
```

[*] https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates